# Problems of creating and opening "Oracle Database Project":The selected file cannot be opened

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, oracle11g

I'd like to ask a question.

I am using VS 2010(10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel), with "Oracle Developer Tools for visual Studio 11.2.0.3.0", Oracle 11 with Windows 10 Pro

When you tried to create a new project of "Oracle Database Project", named "ProjectTest" on C:\Test, I was told

"The selected file cannot be opened. 'C:\Users\wang\AppData\Local\Temp.....\Temp\Project1.oradbproj' cannot be opened because its project type (.oradbproj) is not supported by this version of the application. To open it, please use a version that supports this type of project."

Then in C:\Test, a folder "Project1" was created with solution file ".sln" and ".suo", and an empty folder "Test1", without anywhing.

And then I treid to open an "Oracle Database Project" in C:\Test2, crerated by the others, the same error was told:

"The selected file cannot be opened. 'C:\Test2\Project1.oradbproj' cannot be opened because its project type (.oradbproj) is not supported by this version of the application. To open it, please use a version that supports this type of project."

Could some do me a favour to help me?

Thano you very much

best regards

Martin

Comment: Maybe you need a newer version of VS

Answer (score 0):

maybe i should reinstall Visual Studio